# What is the purpose of NSCC illiquid charges for low-volume stocks?

Tags: united-states, stocks, fees, trading-volume, penny-stocks

I understand the situations in which I will be charged an NSCC illiquid charge, and I have read: [What are NSCC illiquid charges?](https://money.stackexchange.com/questions/23684/what-are-nscc-illiquid-charges) From my understanding, stock brokers pass the NSCC illiquid charge to their clients. What I don't understand is:

- What does the NSCC illiquid charge pay for?
- Who ultimately receives the money from an NSCC illiquid charge? Is it a regulator?